# Solving the inequality between a and b

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, inequalities, exponential-sums

I run into this inequality

$$
(a + b)^{1 - \epsilon} \;a < b
$$

where $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$. What value (w.r.t $a$ and $\epsilon$) should I set $b$ equal to such that this inequality holds for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? (if possible).

What I have gotten so far:

$$
\frac{a + b}{(a + b)^{\epsilon}} \; a < b
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
a^2 + ab < (a + b)^{\epsilon} \; b \leq (a^{\epsilon} + b^{\epsilon}) b
$$
$$
\Downarrow
$$
$$
a^2 + ab < a^{\epsilon}b + b^{1 + \epsilon}
$$

I am struggling to proceed from here.

Comment: are you hoping that the inequality will hold for all $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$? take $\epsilon=1/2$, $a=2$, $b=1$ for a counterexample.

Comment: I guess my question is, suppose this inequality holds, what is the relation between a and b.

Comment: The inequality holds for $\epsilon>1-\ln(b/a)/\ln(a+b)$.  In particular, it will certainly fail when $\epsilon$ is very small.

Comment: I have restated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Why is this question labeled "off-topic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the inequality as
$$f_{p,a}(b):=\frac b{(a+b)^p}>a,\tag{1}$$
where $p:=1-\epsilon\in(0,1)$. We have
$$f'_{p,a}(b)=\frac{a+(1-p)b}{(a+b)^{p+1}}>0$$
for $a,b>0$, so that the function $f_{p,a}$ is continuous and strictly increasing from $0$ to $\infty$ on $(0,\infty)$. So, (1) can be rewritten as
$$b>f_{p,a}^{-1}(a),\tag{1}$$
where $f_{p,a}^{-1}$ is the function inverse to $f_{p,a}^{-1}$.

---

If $p$ is rational, then the function $f_{p,a}^{-1}$ is algebraic. Otherwise, it apparently cannot be expressed in closed form; at least, Mathematica cannot do that:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Suppose $p$ is irrational, say $1 / \sqrt{2}$. Let $p' > p$ be a rational number within $(0, 1)$, can we set $b$ to satisfies: $b > f_{p', a}^{-1}(a)$ since it follows that   $b > f_{p', a}^{-1}(a) > f_{p, a}^{-1}(a)$?

Comment: @Null_Space : No, we do not have the monotonicity in $p$.

Comment: @losif I see. So given an irrational $p$ and some positive integer $a$, we cannot compute the value of $b$ to satisfies the inequality right?

Comment: @Null_Space : Of course, since the function $f_{p,a}$ is continuous and strictly increasing from $0$ to $\infty$ on $(0,\infty)$, you can compute the values of $f^{-1}_{p,a}$ numerically with any degree of accuracy, for any given $p$ and $a$. Since $a$ is an integer, the computation problem is even easier than that. The only thing is that we cannot express $f^{-1}_{p,a}$ in closed form.

Comment: @losif Now I understand. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @losif I have a quick follow-up question regarding the form of the inverse function $f_{p, a}^{-1}$, it is possible that this function is exponential in $a$? ($a$ is on the exponent) My guess is that it is not possible since there is no $\log$ in the function $f_{p, a}$

Comment: @Null_Space : I think it is extremely unlikely that $f_{p,a}^{-1}$ is exponential. Then it would be closed form anyway, and so, Mathematica would likely find that form.